# Match elements of a JSON array

Tags: postgresql, select, json, array

This is a sample table :

```
create table test(
    id int,
    json_key json[]
);

insert into test (id,json_key) values
    (1,array['{"key1":"123"}'::json,'{"key2":"456"}'::json]),
    (2,array['{"key1":"789"}'::json,'{"key2":"456"}'::json]);
```

json_key output is :

```
{{"key1":"123"},{"key2":"456"}}
```

I am trying to execute

```
select * from test 
where json_key->>'key2'='456';
```

but it does not work :( 
how can I run this query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of trying to match something against array elements is using [`ANY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html#AEN21104).  The only thing is to find the right operator that can be used with it.  In this case, `<@` will be our friend (you can find it and others at the [right page of the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE)).  When that's done, it becomes easy:

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE '{"key2": "456"}'::jsonb <@ ANY(json_key::jsonb[]);

 id │                  json_key                   
────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────
  1 │ {"{\"key1\":\"123\"}","{\"key2\":\"456\"}"}
  2 │ {"{\"key1\":\"789\"}","{\"key2\":\"456\"}"}
```

To prove it really does what we expect:

```
test=# SELECT * FROM test WHERE '{"key1": "456"}'::jsonb <@ ANY(json_key::jsonb[]);

 id │ json_key 
────┼──────────

test=# SELECT * FROM test WHERE '{"key1": "123"}'::jsonb <@ ANY(json_key::jsonb[]);

 id │                  json_key                   
────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────
  1 │ {"{\"key1\":\"123\"}","{\"key2\":\"456\"}"}
```

Watch it in action on [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=7f76a7901e93b9404e6171417d5bf25d).